# Set cursor in the same position as selected in a treeview before while reopening the file.

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk

Set cursor in the same position as selected in a treeview before closing that file and while reopening the file i want to set that cursor in same position . I did this using the pygtk and python.

Comment: Is this your own treeview, or the treeview from the file_selection dialog? In the first case, you can simply save the gtk_tree_path and reselect before the second 'open'.

Answer (score 1):

```
last_path = treeview.get_cursor()[0]
## do whatever you want, then finally:
treeview.set_cursor(last_path)
treeview.scroll_to_cell(last_path)
```